# How can I access database from a specific plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a plugin in wordpress which allows users to register on my website. I want to access their profile data (like the username or the profile image) the way I do with *current_user->user_login* but I can't find the correspondent database for that plugin. Is there a way to access the information the users store on their profile? I am a beginner so sorry in advance for any stupid question.

Comment: Corresponding table you mean?

Comment: Yes, I looked everywhere and I can't find any place where the information is stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for a plugin, but for a function. The function you should use for retrieving user meta (the correct name for what you call profile data) is get_user_meta();

An example:

```
// Get the user id
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Get the user meta, in this example 'description'
$user_description = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', true );

// Echo the description
echo $user_description;
```

Look [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) for more information on how to use get_user_meta();